# How to enable support of CPU virtualization on Macbook Pro?

Tags: macos, cpu, virtualization

I have the VirtualBox installed on my Macbook Pro, and I want to install a linux VM on VirtualBox.
When I launched the new VM, it prompts that "Your CPU does not support long mode.  Use a 32bit distribution."

After searching for this problem, I found that support of CPU virtualization is required for this VM.
Then I checked on my Macbook and its CPU is i7 which supports virtualization.
So I guess the problem is related to the OS or EFI version?

OS version: 10.6.8 / EFI version: latest (check on apple.com)

Does anyone know what's the problem of my Macbook?  How can I enable the support of CPU virtualization?

Comment: BTW, I have already enabled option of "Hardware Virtualization" in VM settings

Comment: This may help:  http://kb.parallels.com/en/5653

Comment: You might want to update your OS, 10.6.8 is four years old.  A lot of software has dropped or downgraded support.

Comment: Related: [how to enable virtualization capabilities when running docker in macbook pro](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46751761) is also basically about checking for support, not how to enable.  Implying that if it's supported, it should be enabled, but not clearly saying that.

Answer (score 16):

CPU Virtualization is enabled by default on all MacBooks with compatible CPUs (i7 is compatible).
You can try to [reset PRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) if you think it was disabled somehow, but I doubt it.

I think the issue might be in the old version of OS. If your MacBook is i7, then you better upgrade OS to something newer.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a way to check is virtualization is enabled or disabled by the firmware as suggested by this [link](http://kb.parallels.com/en/5653) in parallels.com.

How to check that Intel VT-x is supported in CPU:

1. Open Terminal application from Application/Utilities
2. Copy/paste command bellow

`sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu.features`

3. You may see output similar to:

`Mac:~ user$ sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu.features
kern.exec: unknown type returned
machdep.cpu.features: FPU VME DE PSE TSC MSR PAE MCE CX8 APIC SEP MTRR PGE MCA CMOV PAT CLFSH DS ACPI MMX FXSR SSE SSE2 SS HTT TM SSE3 MON VMX EST TM2 TPR PDCM`

If you see VMX entry then CPU supports Intel VT-x feature, but it still may be disabled.

Refer to this [link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203296) on Apple.com to enable hardware support for virtualization:

Comment: Why does this have so many upvotes?  It doesn't tell you how to turn on virtualization (like the question asks).  It doesn't even tell you how to check if virtualization is enabled like it claims!  It only tells you if you CPU supports it, which isn't helpful.

Comment: Why you guys keep posting this command everywhere that check if it's supported or not .. and no one on the internet shows us how we can enable it or disable it.

Comment: Downvoting since it does not answer the question of "How to enable support of CPU virtualization"

Answer (score 0):

on Mac only way is to update to the lasted version of macOS
but you till can check if yours is support or not

```
$ sysctl kern.hv_support 
kern.hv_support: 1
```

If it is 1, then your CPU is supported.
If it is 0, it means the Hypervisor.framework cannot be used with your CPU, for a reason or another.

full answer [how-to-enable-virtualization-capabilities-when-running-docker-in-macbook-pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46751761/how-to-enable-virtualization-capabilities-when-running-docker-in-macbook-pro)