# How to check that virtualization is enabled on a macOS

Tags: macos, virtualization

There are already several questions about how to enable virtualization on Macs (e.g. [How to enable support of CPU virtualization on Macbook Pro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580491/how-to-enable-support-of-cpu-virtualization-on-macbook-pro)).  It is often reported that `sysctl -a | grep 'machdep.cpu.feature.*VMX'` should match, but with a caveat: matching means that virtualization is supported by the cpu, not that it is enabled.

Is there a way to check that virtualization *is* enabled?  I'm ready to compile and run a small program if that's what it takes to be able to answer, but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 things which basically tells you if `Intel VMX` is supported and enabled on a machine or not. This is not OS specific but specific to Intel boards.

1. `CPUID.1 will tell you in ecx.BIT[5] == 1 if CPU supports vmx.`
2. `IA32_FEATURE_CONTROL MSR BIT.2 == 1` will tell you if VMX is enabled in normal mode. If BIT.2 is 0 and BIT.0 is 1 in this MSR, this means VMX is disabled and locked in BIOS. You would need to reboot and enable that in BIOS.
3. `Control Register CR4.BIT.13[VMXE] == 1` will tell you that VMX is enabled now on the machine. CPU will `GPF` if `CR4.VMXE` bit is cleared and you try to execute a `VMXON` instruction to enter VMX root mode.

You can write a small program to do this and check what you are missing.