# Intel HAXM is required to run this avd android studio

Tags: android-studio

I am using Android Studio 2.2 (to appropriately follow along an online class). I am using a mac OS High Sierra v 10.13.3, Intel HD Graphics 6000 1536 MB graphics. However, I am receiving the following error:

"Troubleshoot
Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD.
/dev/kvm is not found
Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings, ensure that your Linux distro has working KVM module."

The solutions I found on this site are mostly on Windows, and the mac solutions did not help.

I appreciate any help in this matter as I am desperate to continue.

Comment: https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Installation-Instructions-on-macOS

Comment: Need to format question properly.

Answer (score 0):

you needs to turn on Virtualization in your BIOS setting.

this link will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/35027378/8358956

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have this issue, you need to **enable Hyper-v**.

*Control panel -> Uninstall a program -> Click Turn Windows features on or off -> Expand and check Hyper-v*

2. If your Hyper-v is disabled, you have to **enable virtualization technology**.

   *Open the BIOS to enable virtualization technology.*
3. How to Open BIOS

   *There are two ways to open BIOS*

   Step 1 :

   - On your HP computer, you can open the BIOS at startup or through Windows.
   - If your computer is off, try pressing a hotkey at startup. HP PCs use
     either    f10 or escape as the hotkey,
   - Check your manual to see which to use.
   - Turn the PC on and immediately press f10 or escape repeatedly.
   - the BIOS startup menu should open.

   Step 2 :
   *You can get to the BIOS from Windows.

   - Open the start menu and click settings. scroll down and click update &
     security.
     *Select Recovery then restart now. your computer restarts with a recovery
     menu.
     *Select troubleshoot. click advanced options, then UEFI Firmware settings.
     the BIOS screen opens.
4. After opening the BIOS, enable virtualization technology
5. The whole process I have explained through video.[HAXM is required to run this avd android studio](https://youtu.be/R6xOKuJ5d9E)