# How can I fix "Attach a Debugger or ESC to Cancel" error?

Tags: java, android, debugging

I use Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 2. My OS is win 8.1 Pro. Emulator is Pixel XL API 25. I have JDK-18.0.2 Even there is not any connected phone to my computer I get "Attach a Debugger or ESC to Cancel" error. Emulator doesn't come online. It doesn't work. I have searched and almost tried every solution on stackoverflow. Still getting the same error.

**Gradle Settings**

Gradle User Home: C:\Users\UserName\.gradle

Use Gradle From: 'gradle-wrapper.properties' file

Gradle JDK: Android Studio Default JDK version 11.0.12

JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2\bin (also tried C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.2\bin)

What should I do?

Thank you for responses.

Answer (score 2):

Consider selecting Api level 27 or below, which resolved the same error for me in creating an emulator using Api level 30 or above.

Comment: API level 27 on my Windows OS is working fine. API 31-32 was giving error. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There might be some underlying error you're not seeing. I had the same problem and did this:

1. Launched emulator as usual
2. When `Attach a Debugger or ESC to Cancel` appears, I went on *Task manager* - *Details* tab to see the command line that was used for the process `qemu-...`:
   [image: Task manager - Details]
3. Copied command from *Command line* column
4. Pasted in command prompt
5. Forced task `qemu-...` end
6. Delete any `.lock` file that you find in the virtual device folder
7. Launched command
8. Finally saw some actual errors appear

My issue was due to some missing dlls

Answer (score 0):

Install newest update to android emulator 31.3.10 . Then restart computer and after showing window with "Attach a Debugger or ESC to Cancel" press ESC button ... Android emulator will start .
[image: Attach a debugger or EC to cancel]

Second, delete all android virtual devices and install them again.

It's a bug and probably will eventually be solved by Google.

Comment: Thank you for your response but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Go to BIOS to see that virtualization is enabled ...   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580491/how-to-enable-support-of-cpu-virtualization-on-macbook-pro

Comment: it seems its a bug...https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/243054171?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have 2 different versions of adb.exe
if you are a windows user, open task manager and find adb.exe in the process list, right-click on it and choose Open File Location, remove that folder or move it to a temporary place,(make sure you killed adb.exe using task manager before moving it).
then run the emulator again and see if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem but my emulator is working fine. Use Android 9.0
and Pixel 3 API 28.
The dialog box "attach a debugger or esc to cancel" occurs but the emulator works, you need to cancel this dialog box.

--->> use android 9.0 and pixel 3 api 28 emulator

Answer (score 0):

Just press the escape key. It solves the problem. I also suffered for 3 months because of this. But now, the baby is working.

Answer (score 0):

It no longer asks me the "Attach debugger or Esc to cancel" window after upgrading to the following.

1. AS: Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1
2. Emulator Version: 31.3.14

I have also Unchecked the following checkboxes in Android Studio

1. "System > Settings/Preferences > Tools > Emulator > Launch in tool Window"
2. "System > Settings/Preferences > Build Execution Deployment > Debugger > Hotswap > Enable hotswap agent for Groovy code"

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From issue tracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/243054171?pli=1

Solution in comment 16 worked like a charm:

ri...@zimperium.comri...@zimperium.com #16Nov 8, 2022 01:44PM
Looks like the problem is Google has compiled swiftshader with -DEBUGGER_WAIT_DIALOG. According to sources of swiftshader, a way to disable this dialog is to set environment variable **SWIFTSHADER_DISABLE_DEBUGGER_WAIT_DIALOG** to **1**. An alternative workaround would be to change -gpu mode away from swiftshader.

Answer (score 0):

Go to SDK Manager, then go to SDK Platforms > Select appropriate API level(Which you have selected for Emulator) > Press OK.
Restart Emulator , then after emulator boot up ; run your code.
Hope it would help you !

Answer (score -1):

I just closed error message and emulator opened fine. Nexus 6 API 22.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).