# how i can fix this attach a debugger error?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

[error massage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3ofY.jpg)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3ofY.jpg)

[the error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VP9Ds.jpg)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73351771/how-can-i-fix-attach-a-debugger-or-esc-to-cancel-error/73384041#73384041

Comment: tried everything in there nothing works

Comment: Welcome to the site, please write down the error that you're getting and what you have attempted to do, so it'll be searchable and we'll know not to offer things you tried.

Comment: Please give background on what program you are using and what you did when you got that error. Also anything you have tried to fix it. @MohmedAshraf