# VS2022 Maui, how do I fix waiting for debugger deploying to emulator

Tags: android, maui, visual-studio-2022

Hello I am having a first look around VS2022 Maui. I can run the sample app on a windows machine but when I try to run on the emulator I get "Waiting for Debugger, Attach a debugger or escape to exit"

Not sure if it is the Android device manager, I have the default Pixel5 API 33 and when I click start it throws this error[image: Error message]

I'd be grateful if anybody could point me in the right direction

Thanks

Comment: Sounds silly - but have you tried hitting ESC?  That's what fixed it for me when I had this issue.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73351771/how-can-i-fix-attach-a-debugger-or-esc-to-cancel-error

Comment: Yes, emulator does not load, VS reports failed to deploy so that isn't it!
Going to try deploying to physical device (handset on charge)

Comment: potentially silly but have you tried opening the Simulator first?  Completing ignoring Visual Studio all together.  Something funky has gone on with your Android install, so giving it a boot up itself might be what's needed.  Worse case, I'd actually recommend doing physical device testing over the emulator as .NET MAUI likes to return completely different results in the emulator sometimes.

Comment: Hi Thanks for taking the time to reply.
Not sure what just happened but the emulator just loaded and ran the application but I can't recreate.
may I ask what should I run and from what folder? 
Is this a commandline thing?

Comment: The plot thickens. The problem seems to be API specific. API 28 runs fine in the emulator. I still get a debugger message but clicking cancel runs the emulator.
29-33 to will not run

Comment: You can try to delete the emulator and create a new one.